# Issue with passing returned array from model in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm having some trouble using a custom library to create threaded comments in Codeigniter 3.

The library is working when i manually declare an array in the controller, however when i try and pass an array from the model, it doesnt.

Example using an array coded into the controller:

```
$comments = array(  
array (
  'first_name' => 'James',
  'last_name' => 'Smith',
  'country' => 'UK',
  'profile' => 'avatar87.jpg',
  'id' => '1',
  'member_id' =>  '18',
  'policy_id' => '6',
  'comment' => '<p>This is my comment.Do you agree?</p>',
  'submitted' => '2015-09-22 07:20:21',
  'parent_id' => NULL),
   array (
  'first_name' => 'Peter',
  'last_name' => 'Green',
  'country' => 'Australia',
  'profile' => 'avatar88.jpg',
  'id' => '2',
  'member_id' =>  '18',
  'policy_id' => '6',
  'comment' => '<p>This is my comment.Do you agree?</p>',
  'submitted' => '2015-09-22 07:20:21',
  'parent_id' => '1'),
   array (
  'first_name' => 'Ollie',
  'last_name' => 'Ford',
  'country' => 'Australia',
  'profile' => 'avatar85.jpg',
  'id' => '3',
  'member_id' =>  '18',
  'policy_id' => '6',
  'comment' => '<p>This is my comment.Do you agree?</p>',
  'submitted' => '2015-09-22 07:20:21',
  'parent_id' => '1'),
         );

 $this->data['comments'] = $comments;
```

With the above all is working, however when i try this:

```
$comments = $this->question_model->get_policy_comments($id);
$this->data['comments'] = $comments;
```

It doesnt work.

Here is the $comments array returned from the model.

```
 array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      'first_name' => string 'Ollie' (length=5)
      'last_name' => string 'Falle' (length=5)
      'country' => string 'Australia' (length=9)
      'profile' => string 'avatar87.jpg' (length=12)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'member_id' => string '18' (length=2)
      'policy_id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'comment' => string '<p>This is my comment.Do you agree?</p>' (length=39)
      'submitted' => string '2015-09-22 07:20:21' (length=19)
      'parent_id' => string 'NULL' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=10)
      'first_name' => string 'Ollie' (length=5)
      'last_name' => string 'Falle' (length=5)
      'country' => string 'Australia' (length=9)
      'profile' => string 'avatar87.jpg' (length=12)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'member_id' => string '18' (length=2)
      'policy_id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'comment' => string '<p>Blah blah blah</p>' (length=21)
      'submitted' => string '2015-09-22 15:00:00' (length=19)
      'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=10)
      'first_name' => string 'Ollie' (length=5)
      'last_name' => string 'Falle' (length=5)
      'country' => string 'Australia' (length=9)
      'profile' => string 'avatar87.jpg' (length=12)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'member_id' => string '18' (length=2)
      'policy_id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'comment' => string '<p>Hello is it me your looking for.</p>' (length=39)
      'submitted' => string '2015-09-22 13:39:46' (length=19)
      'parent_id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Am i missing something with the array?

Any help would be appreciated.

For reference, here the library its using.

```
 <?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Threaded
{

    public $parents  = array();
    public $children = array();

    /**
     * @param array $comments
     */
    public function arrange($comments)
    {
        foreach ($comments as $comment)
        {

            if ($comment['parent_id'] === NULL)
            {
                $this->parents[$comment['id']][] = $comment;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->children[$comment['parent_id']][] = $comment;
            }
        }
        $this->print_comments();
    }

    private function tabulate($depth)
    {
        for ($depth; $depth > 0; $depth--)
        {
           // echo "t";
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $comment
     * @param int $depth
     */
    private function format_comment($comment, $depth)
    {

        //echo "n";

        $this->tabulate($depth+1);

        echo "<li>";
        echo $comment['first_name'];
        echo $comment['last_name'];
        echo $comment['country'];
        echo $comment['profile'];
        echo $comment['member_id'];
        echo $comment['policy_id'];
        echo $comment['comment'];
        echo $comment['submitted'];
        echo $comment['id'];
        echo $comment['parent_id'];
        echo "</li>";
    }

    /**
     * @param array $comment
     * @param int $depth
     */
    private function print_parent($comment, $depth = 0)
    {
        $this->tabulate($depth);
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($comment as $c)
        {
            $this->format_comment($c, $depth);

            if (isset($this->children[$c['id']]))
            {
                $this->print_parent($this->children[$c['id']], $depth + 1);
            }
        }
        $this->tabulate($depth);
        echo "</ul>";
    }

    private function print_comments()
    {
        foreach ($this->parents as $c)
        {
            $this->print_parent($c);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: As @DOfficial mentioned, it seems the structure of the array is different. Any idea on how i can get it to match?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your logic is to process the data but (unless it is a typo) your static array looks like

```
array(data),  array(data),  array(data)  //with an unopened )
```

and the array returned from the model is

```
array(  array(data),  array(data),  array(data)  )
```

what are you trying to do with the array and how did you achieve the output from the model (ie: var_dump();, print_r(); )? Also how are you defining $comments in the first example?

Comment: Hi @DOfficial, Thanks for the response. The Threaded library needs the array to be in the same format as the static array example. The returned array from the model is using the var_dump($comments). In the static example, i am simply passing the data via $this->data['comments']=$comments; and the view has this <?php $this->threaded->arrange($comments); ?>

Comment: Did you update the code? The arrays seem to be matching now.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign to comments in a single line

```
$this->data['comments'] = $this->question_model->get_policy_comments($id);
```

and just check it by below code and see the pattern of your array

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($comments); die();
```

Answer (score 0):

So the arrays look to be correct now. However I think your issue is that in your static array you are actually passing a NULL value where in the returned array your 'NULL' value is actually interpreted as a string not NULL.

Before passing the array:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($comments); $i++){
    foreach($comments[$i] as $k => $v){
        if(strtoupper($v) === 'NULL'){
           $comments[$k] = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

or in your model

```
public function arrange($comments)
{
    foreach ($comments as $comment)
    {

        if ($comment['parent_id'] === NULL || $comment['parent_id']==='NULL')
        {
            $this->parents[$comment['id']][] = $comment;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->children[$comment['parent_id']][] = $comment;
        }
    }
    $this->print_comments();
}
```